# Unknown error communicating between PHP and Actionscript

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, communication, urlloader

I've got a problem that's either insanely simple or complex, it's up to you to find out. I've been working on trying to incorporate the URL Loader class into the beginners graphics program - Stencyl. I am fluent in HTML, CSS and PHP but actionscript is completely new to me so I really could use with a hand. Here's what I've got:
There are 4 files hosted on my domain:

Webpage.html

Stylesheet.css

RequestData.php

FlashDoc.swf

The html and css code is simple, no problems there and the swf file embed in the html document. The flash file is a simple form with a text field, submit button and two dynamic text fields. The code goes as follows:

```
// Btn listener
submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnDown);
// Btn Down function
function btnDown(event:MouseEvent):void {


// Assign a variable name for our URLVariables object
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
// Build the varSend variable
// Be sure you place the proper location reference to your PHP config file here
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.mywebsite.com/config_flash.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;
// Build the varLoader variable
var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

variables.uname = uname_txt.text;
variables.sendRequest = "parse"; 
// Send the data to the php file
varLoader.load(varSend);

// When the data comes back from PHP we display it here 
function completeHandler(event:Event):void{

var phpVar1 = event.target.data.var1;
var phpVar2 = event.target.data.var2;

result1_txt.text = phpVar1;
result2_txt.text = phpVar2;

} 


}
```

I then have a small PHP file with this code:

```
<?php
// Only run this script if the sendRequest is from our flash application
if ($_POST['sendRequest'] == "parse") {
// Access the value of the dynamic text field variable sent from flash
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
// Print  two vars back to flash, you can also use "echo" in place of print
print "var1=My name is $uname...";
print "&var2=...$uname is my name.";

}

?>
```

This is, for some reason, not working. The result is just two blank text fields and being an actionscript noob, I have no idea what is up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your issue is both simple and surprising, if you're not used to AS3.

In AS3, the flash.* classes tend to, when a setter is used, make and store a copy of the passed object.
Since they store a copy, any modification on the original instance after the setter isn't applied on the copy, and thus is ignored.

It is the case of, for example, `DisplayObject.filters`, `ContextMenu.customItems` or `URLRequest.data`.

In your code, you are setting `varSend.data = variables` **before** filling `variables`. You should do the reverse :

```
variables.uname = uname_txt.text;
variables.sendRequest = "parse"; 
varSend.data = variables;
// Send the data to the php file
varLoader.load(varSend);
```

Only some classes do that, and even then, they usually don't do it with all of their setters.

Comment: Actually, there's still an issue with this code. There doesn't seem to be a response. Could it be a flash security issue?